# Dotnetnuke: Users with different roles in different hierarchical contexts? (Group/Folder/Sub-Site?)

Tags: dotnetnuke, hierarchy, roles

I would like UserA to be an Administrator in dnn/SomeCountry/SomeDepartment/SomeArea 
But only be an Author in dnn/SomeOtherCountry/SomeOtherDepartment/SomeOtherArea

I would like the hierarchy to be easy for an end user to create and preferably light weight.
I would then like the page at the end of the tree to show a custom module based on the role.

Is this possible do this with an existing nestable content item? (folder or group or sub-site or sub-page etc)

It looks like i could do this with sub-site but I think a sub-site is far to heavy for what i am looking for (lots of duplicated css etc), some type of 'folder' would be a better fit.

Is there a content type that already supports this? 
Is there a module that already supports this?

If not then how easy would this be to implement?

p.s i tried posting [this question](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Forums/forumid/118/postid/478658/scope/posts.aspx) on the DNN forum and go no response

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't likely be able to do this easily with the Community Edition of DotNetNuke, but using the more granular permission model in Professional Edition I believe you could do this fairly easily.

They wouldn't be "admins" but you can give roles the ability to "ADD" pages at different hierarchies, something you can't do in CE.

Comment: I'm not sure that is what I am looking for. That might allow me to create fine grained permission decisions at a specific depth, but not allow me to assign roles.

Comment: That is correct, assigning roles is done pretty much only by administrators, you wouldn't be able to let non-admins define and assign roles. They could define what those roles can do on their pages .